# working with ajax request to get data from controller in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to get data from my a method in my controller. I have written the AJAX code in order to get data from the controller but it does not seem to do the job (not pulling data from controller). Maybe I am missing something either in the controller of the AJAX request method.

I have two dropdowns alongside each other. I am trying to populate the second dropdown by getting data from the controller based on the selection of first dropdown that the user selects.

I would really appreciate some guidance or help on this matter.

```csharp
public ActionResult ptdrloFilter(int id)
{
    int customerId = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerID"];
    IUnitOfWork uow = DataAccess.GetUnitOfWork();
    using (ManageProductTemplate ptLogic = new ManageProductTemplate(ref uow))
    {
        List<ProductTemplate> currentpt = ptLogic.GetBy(x => x.ProductTemplateID == id);
        List<string> returnDisString = new List<string>();
        List<string> pt = new List<string>();

        var getDRString = (from drule in Drulelogic.GetCustomerProdIndexString(customerId, id).List
                           select new { drule.Name, drule.DistributionRuleID }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in getDRString)
        {
            returnDisString.Add(item.Name);
        }
        returnDisString = returnDisString.Distinct().ToList();
        return Json(returnDisString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);               
    }
}
```

```js
function drFilter() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "json",
        data: { id: 1 },
        url: @Url.Action("ptdrloFilter"),
        success: function(result) {
            drFilter(result);
        }
    });

    var dataInJSONForm = JSON.stringify(result);
    var datainJSObjectForm = JSON.parse(dataInJSONForm);

    $('#dd1').on('change', function (e) {
        var valueChosenInddl2 = $(this).val();
        var options = datainJSObjectForm[valueChosenInddl2];
        var $subselect = $('#subselect');
        $subselect.children().detach();

        for (var property in options) {
            $subselect.append($('<option>', { 
                value: property, 
                text: options[property] 
            }));
        };
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="editor-field">
    <select id="dd1">
        <option value="Default">Default</option>
        <option value="PTDR">PT/DR</option>
        <option value="All">All</option>
    </select>

    <select id="subselect"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your ajax Call: it missing controller name

```
$.ajax({
    type: "json",
    data: {id: 1},
    url:'@Url.Action("ptdrloFilter","ControllerName")',
    success: function(result) {
      //
    },
    error:function(ex)
    {
       //
    }
});
```

You have also write  `drFilter(result)` but there is **no any parameter in function**

Comment: This may or may not matter. If the action is on the same controller as the calling one then you don't need to do this

Comment: can you explain more about the parameter in function as i am new to ajax.

Comment: In ajax success you have written drFilter(result) mean you pass result as parameter to function drFilter, but in your actual function  not accept any parameter